# Shake: Inherit stderr

Tags: shake-build-system

Using [Shake](https://shakebuild.com/), I am calling [cdparanoia](https://www.xiph.org/paranoia/).  `cdparanoia` outputs a useful progress meter (including graphics to display issues) when its stderr is connected to a terminal; but not otherwise.  The `--stderr-progress` forces some progress output, but it's not as useful, and would require a chunk of work to interpret.

I would like to run the cdparanoia command with its stderr inherited directly, (or otherwise connected to `/dev/tty`).  I have tried using the `FileStderr` option set to `/dev/tty`, but that doesn't help - I guess `shake` is still sucking in the stderr, and then passing it onto /dev/tty.

Is there a way to convince shake to run a command with its stderr truly inherited?  Or should I use System.Process (or similar) for this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you'd need to use `System.Process`, but it's feasible that Shake could offer a way to inherit handles. The reason Shake doesn't currently offer inheriting is because bad things might happen if you ran two simultaneous processes inherited.

Comment: fair point, that would be problematic.  Okie dokie, I've got a `System.Process` version working, and now I'll feel less like I missed something.  Thanks Neil!